# Why is the counter not working

Tags: c++

I am trying to help a friend out and I can't seem to get it guys. I don't know why but several variables are not showing up right.

I got it knocked down to where i think the problem is, but i don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
//declaring variables
ifstream myfile("input.txt");
double grades[26];
unsigned scores[8] = {0};




//getting data from text file
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            myfile >> grades[i];
            cin.ignore();


    if((grades[i] >= 175) && (grades[i] <= 200)) scores[7]++; 
    else if(grades[i] >= 150)                    scores[6]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 125)                    scores[5]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 100)                    scores[4]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 75)                     scores[3]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 50)                     scores[2]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 25)                     scores[1]++;
    else if(grades[i] >= 0)                      scores[0]++;
      }

//outputing results


for(int z = 0; z < 200; z += 25)
{
    if(z == 175)
        cout << "Number of students between 175 and 200: " << scores[z] << endl;
    else
        cout << "Number of students between " << z << " and " << z + 24 << ": " << scores[z]<< endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

The file it is extracting from has this in it.

```
76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167, 200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87, 35, 157, 189
```

I know the problem is somewhere in the

```
//getting data from text file
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            myfile >> grades[i];
            cin.ignore();
```

I don't know what to do to fix it, and i don't know why it is broken.

the output was

```
   Number of students between 0 and 24: 25
Number of students between 25 and 49: 32767
Number of students between 50 and 74: 3900547712
Number of students between 75 and 99: 0
Number of students between 100 and 124: 0
Number of students between 125 and 149: 32760
Number of students between 150 and 174: 0
Number of students between 175 and 200: 32767
```

when the output should have been.
Number of students between 0-24: 12

i don't know why it isn't working right. 
Thanks for letting me know to put the output on here too... forgot.

Comment: What's the expected result?  What's the actual result?  What's telling you something is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want your counters to be a `double`?

Comment: yes the out output was crazy. like 2.55546846312 e -1665

Comment: the expected output for score1 was 12

Comment: Number of students between 0-24: 25
Number of students between 25-49: 2.07463e-317
Number of students between 50-74: 1.28458e-312
Number of students between 75-99: 1
Number of students between 100-124: 6.91603e-310
Number of students between 125-149: 2.07367e-317
Number of students between 150-174: 0
Number of students between 175-200: 0
this was the output

Comment: I have never seen using increment ++ operator with floating point variables...

Comment: Since you're always counting by the same amount for the ranges, making the scores into an array would save you from having to use 8 variables like 3 different times.

Comment: @chris this would save time. I will try to update with this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Several things you can do to make your code more readable, and hence, spot logic errors easier...**

Why don't you make the scores variables an array?  Secondly, why use `double`?  That's not necessary, is it?

```
unsigned scores[8] = {0};
```

Why so many `if`s?  Once a value is found to be within a certain range, why continue to see if it falls within ranges you know it cannot?

```
if((grades[i] >= 175) && (grades[i] <= 200)) scores[7]++; 
else if(grades[i] >= 150)                    scores[6]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 125)                    scores[5]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 100)                    scores[4]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 75)                     scores[3]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 50)                     scores[2]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 25)                     scores[1]++;
else if(grades[i] >= 0)                      scores[0]++;
```

You can output the results using an array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if(i == 7)
        cout << "Number of students between 175 and 200: " << score[i] << endl;
    else
        cout << "Number of students between " << (i * 25) << " and " << (i * 25 + 24) << ": " << score[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: very nice. I will plug it in.

Comment: ok good news and bad. The good is i worked with what you showed me. Bad news is i don't know why it gives me that output.

Comment: @HankBates Just realized I made a mistake in the output loop.  Please revise your code.

Comment: now has this output. 
Number of students between 0 and 24: 25
Number of students between 25 and 49: 0
Number of students between 50 and 74: 0
Number of students between 75 and 99: 1
Number of students between 100 and 124: 0
Number of students between 125 and 149: 0
Number of students between 150 and 174: 0
Number of students between 175 and 200: 0

Comment: After `myfile >> grades[i];` put this statement: `cout << "Grade " << i << ": " << grades[i] << endl;`.  Is what's in the array what you expect?

Comment: the first one yes but then it goes nuts after that

Comment: I'm not too versed in C++, but maybe you need to throw away the `,`. Is that what `cin.ignore()` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you're going for, but just FYI:

```
double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8 = 0.0;
```

This line will only initialize `score8` to 0.

Comment: @Hank Bates: You missed a semicolon, and didn't declare `facepalm`.